# Delphi Rest Api Google Drive Upload File

Tags: rest, delphi, google-drive-api

I'm using Delphi Rest Client component to upload file to Google Drive. 
I use a resumable download. After the first request, the response code should come 308 upload is not complete, and afterwards it is necessary to send parts of the files.
`System.HTTPPClient` is trying to do something, because by default 308 = permanent redirect and eventually gives an Access Violation. How can this situation be solved?

This is upload file

```
UploadStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
fFile := TFileStream.Create(fileName,fmOpenRead);
GetMem(buffer, onePartion);

fFileSize := fFile.Size;
alreadyWrite := 0;
try
    while(fFile.Position < fFile.Size) do
  begin
    FillChar(buffer[0], onePartion, #0);
    UploadStream.Clear;

    liReaded := fFile.Read(buffer[0], onePartion);
    UploadStream.Write(buffer[0], liReaded);
    UploadStream.Position := 0;

    addAuthParam;

    fRESTRequest.Params.Add;
    fRESTRequest.Params[1].Kind:=TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER;
        fRESTRequest.Params[1].name:='Content-Range';
        fRESTRequest.Params[1].Options:=[poDoNotEncode];
        fRESTRequest.Params[1].Value:='bytes ' + IntToStr(alreadyWrite) + '-' + IntToStr(alreadyWrite+liReaded-1) + '/' + IntToStr(fFileSize);
        fRESTRequest.ClearBody;
        fRESTRequest.AddBody(UploadStream,ctAPPLICATION_ZIP);
    try
        fRESTRequest.Execute;
    except

    end;


    alreadyWrite := alreadyWrite + liReaded;
  end;
```

This System.Net.HTTPClient

```
if LRequest.FCancelled then
    Exit;
  LExecResult := DoExecuteRequest(LRequest, LResponse, AContentStream);
  if LRequest.FCancelled then
    Exit;
  case LExecResult of
    TExecutionResult.Success:
      begin
        if not SameText(LRequest.FMethodString, sHTTPMethodHead) then
          LResponse.DoReadData(LResponse.FStream);
        if LRequest.FCancelled then
          Exit;
        Status := LResponse.GetStatusCode;
        case Status of
          200:
            begin
              Break;
            end;
          401:
            begin
              State.Status := InternalState.ServerAuthRequired;
            end;
          407:
            begin
              State.Status := InternalState.ProxyAuthRequired;
            end;
          else
            begin
              case Status of
                301..304, 307:
                  if FHandleRedirects and (LRequest.FMethodString <> sHTTPMethodHead) then
                  begin
                    Inc(State.Redirections);
                    if State.Redirections > FMaxRedirects then
                      raise ENetHTTPRequestException.CreateResFmt(@SNetHttpMaxRedirections, [FMaxRedirects]);
                  end
                  else
                    Break;
              else
              end;
              State.Status := InternalState.Other;
              if DoProcessStatus(LRequest, LResponse) then
                Break;
            end;
        end;
      end;
```

Status = 308, then do function DoProcessStatus(LRequest, LResponse)

```
function TWinHTTPClient.DoProcessStatus(const ARequest: IHTTPRequest; const AResponse: IHTTPResponse): Boolean;
var
  LRequest: TWinHTTPRequest;
  LResponse: TWinHTTPResponse;
  LURI: TURI;
begin
  LRequest := ARequest as TWinHTTPRequest;
  LResponse := AResponse as TWinHTTPResponse;
  // If the result is true then the while ends

  Result := True;
  if (AResponse.StatusCode >= 300) and (AResponse.StatusCode < 400) then //Redirect
  begin
    LURI := TURI.Create(TURI.PathRelativeToAbs(LResponse.GetHeaderValue('Location'), LRequest.FURL));
if SameText(LRequest.GetMethodString, 'POST')
  and ( (AResponse.StatusCode >= 301) and (AResponse.StatusCode <= 303) ) then
  begin
    LRequest.FMethodString := 'GET'; // Change from POST to GET
    LRequest.FSourceStream := nil;  // Donot send any data
  end;

    LRequest.UpdateRequest(LURI);
    LResponse.UpdateHandles(LRequest.FWConnect, LRequest.FWRequest);
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

LURI := TURI.Create(TURI.PathRelativeToAbs(LResponse.GetHeaderValue('Location'), LRequest.FURL));

On this line - AV. I think because Response doesn't have header with this name, and he mustn't have this header.

Comment: I think you should add an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your q if you want help with this.

Comment: @MartynA im edited Q